# Audio devices detected, but no sound output - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

The problem is that i don't have any sound output on Ubuntu 22.04.
The audio card is detected correctly, it is not a hardware problem because it works correctly on windows. In the settings even show an indication of the volume of sound that should be heard. However, nothing is heard in the laptop speakers.
I can use audio Bluetooth devices such as headphones.

```
#lspci -v
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20) (prog-if 80)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 176, IOMMU group 14
Memory at 6021288000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at 6021000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

After moving from ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.15.0-69-lowlatency/now 5.15.0-69.76 amd64 to ubuntu 22.10 with kernel lowlatency/kinetic-updates, kinetic-security, now 5.19.0.1021.17 amd64 there was no sound. And on this settings page https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyk5H.png there was an error showing when clicking front left or front right.

I launched `sudo apt reinstall pulseaudio` and straight away the sound worked.

Comment: There is not Ubuntu 22.01

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, today I opened the laptop and the sound works properly, doing absolutely nothing. Probably yesterday, trying to fix the problem, I uninstalled and reinstalled alsa and pulseaudio. Maybe that's where the problem was solved.

Comment: Hello, I am having the exact same problem. The audio card is detected correctly and everything works on Windows. Could you please provide the steps you followed that could solve the problem? I already tried reinstalling alsa-base and pulseaudio and nothing happened.

Comment: In my case if I plug in headphones they won't work either.

Comment: I have no answer to this problem.
I had to reinstall Ubuntu after first post and I had the same problem again, I reinstalled alsa-base and pulseaudio without any effect. I played with alsamixer a bit, also without an immediate result. Then suddenly the sound started working. Moreover, previously connected bluetooth headsets are no longer connected. More precisely, it connects and then disconnects. I think that in some respects version 22.04 still has some problems.
I use it in the hope that it will solve another problem with wifi after suspend.